# C# User Control (MVVM) surface a property in MV

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, code-behind

I feel though i may be missing somethig here, or its not doable (which i find hard to belive).

I have a UserControl thats using MVVM archtitecture.

The UserControl looks like this.

```
 public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        private string _labelContents;

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new UserControl1_VM();
        }
    }
```

The VM looks like this.

public class UserControl1_VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private string _labelContents = "Set from VM";

```
    public string LabelContent
    {
        get => _labelContents;
        set { _labelContents = value; OnPropertyChanged("LabelContent"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I want to be able to put in a MainView or similar this:

```
  <mv:UserControl1 LabelContent="My Text"></mv:UserControl1>
```

But VS states that it "Cannot relsolve symbol LabelContent". Which is understandable as its in the view model. Without putting that Property in to the code behind in the UserControl, and passing the value through it seems impossible. I may just be looking for the wrong thing.

This is a very basic exaple, but LabelContent i think needs to be a dependancy properties because it is bound to it self i.e ulimately.

```
<mv:UserControl1 LabelContent="{Binding LabelText}"></mv:UserControl1>
```

Any help with this would be great, as it has me scratching my head, and making me bald!!

Just to let you know if its not a Dependancy Property this works, but seems very clumsy.

Cheers

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need any view models for UserControl, just a dependency property:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string LabelContent
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LabelContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
    (
        nameof(LabelContent),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(UserControl1),
        new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty)
    );    
}
```

then put it in a view and assign or bind property:

```
<mv:UserControl1 Name="uc1" LabelContent="My Text"/>

<mv:UserControl1 Name="uc2" LabelContent="{Binding Path=LabelContent, ElementName=uc1}"/>
```

Comment: Exactly.  ASh beat me to it.  Once you have it as a dependency property like this, then you can put any literal string OR bind any object you want to it.  It could be your dedicated view-model set in your `DataContext`, like this `<mv:UserControl1 LabelContent="{Binding LabelText}">` or it could be different object with a string property named `SomeOtherText` where you write the binding and explicitly specify the binding's `Source` property.  `<mv:UserControl1 LabelContent="{Binding Source=..., Path=SomeOtherText}">`  (Substittue an object for "`...`" via `ElementName`, `RelativeSource`, etc)

Comment: So the way MVVM was explained to me was that it was to cut down the code behind, and keep the interface and code seperate. Are you saying its not worth it in this case?

Comment: @WJProctor, I'm not saying any such thing.

Comment: @ASh, but if i had a view model and it wanted to use that LabelContent, how could i do that? This is a very basic example and i have reason for other actions to have a View Model?

Comment: set uc1.DataContext: DataContext = new UserControl1_VM. then bidning `<mv:UserControl1 Name="uc1" LabelContent="{Binding Path=LabelContent}"/>` will work. The main difference: DataContext (view model) is assigned from outside of UserControl

Comment: Simply keep in mind that UserControls, like any other controls, do not have private view models. Moreover they never explicitly set their own DataContext. They expose bindable dependency properties and implement their logic in their code behind. Anything else you may read on the internet is plain wrong.

Comment: Much of the code-behind that MVVM helps to remove is the code that typically would be written to procedurally update the user interface.  By tying UI properties to view-model properties *declaratively*, in XAML, with bindings, you allow WPF do the work of monitoring for changes and updating when necessary.  A`DataContext` can sometimes make writing those XAML bindings simpler because it saves you from having to specify the source of every binding.  But is it is far from necessary and sometimes a barrier to re-usability